# Can a contract address send tokens it doesn't have?

Tags: tokens

I am trying to decipher the transfer logs of the transaction `0x57d755615684d53415cf2d47004f46d78478fd81df886d86e0f6f2066f222b2f`.

Seemingly, the addresses `0x8971b0eacedda995a6dfddd82696c83d2278e233` swaps WETH for CREAM swap on Sushiswap. However, `0x8971..` receives CREAM without sending any WETH. Instead, the contract address `0xd9e1cE17f2641f24aE83637ab66a2cca9C378B9F` sends the WETH. Now the part I don't understand is that the contract address `0xd9e1..` doesn't have any WETH prior to this transaction.

Here are the event logs:

[image]

How is this possible? What am I missing here?